# avoid expensive setup in timeit.repeat() benchmark

Tags: python, profiling, benchmarking, timing, timeit

I'm trying to measure the execution time of a small Python code snippet of mine and I'm wondering what's the best way to do so.

Ideally, I would like to run some sort of setup (which takes a loooong time), then run some test code a couple of times, and get the minimum time of these runs.

`timeit()` seemed appropriate, but I'm not sure how to obtain the minimum time without re-executing the setup. Small code snippet demonstrating the question:

```
import timeit

setup = 'a = 2.0'  # expensive
stmt = 'b = a**2'  # also takes significantly longer than timer resolution

# this executes setup and stmt 10 times and the minimum of these 10 
# runs is returned:
timings1 = timeit.repeat(stmt = stmt, setup = setup, repeat = 10, number = 1)

# this executes setup once and stmt 10 times but the overall time of
# these 10 runs is returned (and I would like to have the minimum 
# of the 10 runs):
timings2 = timeit.repeat(stmt = stmt, setup = setup, repeat = 1, number = 10)
```

Comment: Can you store the result of the setup routine in a variable?

Comment: We cannot store the result in a string because more complex datatypes are involved (scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `datetime` to do your timing for you?

```
start = datetime.datetime.now()
print datetime.datetime.now() - start #prints a datetime.timedelta object`
```

That will give you the time elapsed and you can control where it started with tiny overhead.

Edit: This is a video of a guy who uses it also for doing some timing, it seems to be the easiest way to get the running time. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iw9-GckD-gQ